# Google captcha v3 button twice click is need to complete action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-calendar-api

I just installed recaptcha v3 on a form and I found that the submit button needs to be clicked 2x to make it work.First submit it will get the captcha validation. After the second click it will pass redirect.

Html code

```
<div class="form_wrpr">
   <f:form.hidden id="g-recaptcha-response" property="g-recaptcha-response" />
    <button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-blue" id="reg-submit"
     data-sitekey="{fields.clientKey}" data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit' type= "submit">
   {fields.Button}</button>
</div>
```

Script

```
$("#reg-submit").on('click', function(){if($('#company').val() == '') {
$('#company_error').text($('#company_error').data("error-mandatory"));
isvalid4 = false;
 }  if(!isvalid4) {
return false;  }
if (grecaptcha.getResponse().length != 0) {
$("#reg-submit").attr("disabled", true);
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: $('#form-ajaxurl').val(),
data: $('#demo_form').serialize(),
success: function(data){
    $('#reg-submit').attr("disabled", false);
    var output = JSON.parse(data);
    if(output.error == 1) {
        $('#form-errors').html(output.result);
    } 
    else if(output.error == 2){
        $('#form-errors').html(output.result);
    } else {
     window.location.href = 'test.com'+output.result;
    }  } });   }else    {  var elementClicked = 0;
    $(".g-recaptcha").on('click', function(){
         elementClicked = 1; if( elementClicked == 1)
            {  $('#g_captchaerror').text('');   } });   if(elementClicked == 0)
    { isvalid4 = false;
    $('#g_captchaerror').text($('#g_captchaerror').data("error-mandatory"));   
    } } });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code creates a button that a user must click on in order to complete the CAPTCHA challenge. When the button is clicked, the grecaptcha.execute() function is called, which will trigger the reCAPTCHA v3 verification process.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var alreadySubmitted = false;//adding a extra variable to check already submitted.
  $("#reg-submit").on('click', function(){
  if(!isvalid4) {
    return false;
  }
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('clientkey', {
      action: 'submit'
    }).then(function(token) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $('#form-ajaxurl').val(),
        data: $('#demo_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          // $('#reg-submit').attr("disabled", false);
          var output = JSON.parse(data);
          if (output.error == 1) {
            $('#form-errors').html(output.result);
          } else if(output.error == 2) {
            $('#form-errors').html(output.result);
          } else {
            window.location.href = 'test.com'+output.result;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: grecaptcha.execute(); 
Added the execute code in my script.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).